# Can I use a Transit UK Visa to visit London, while in transit between Frankfurt and Paris?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, philippines

I am from a Philippine passport holder and I am planning to travel from Paris then London (for less than 48 hours) and then to Frankfurt for my flight to New York. I have a few questions with regard to my situation:

1. Is it possible to just get a UK Visitor in Transit Visa instead of a full UK Tourist Visa for my stay in the UK?
2. I haven't booked my flight yet but my intended Paris-London and London-Frankfurt flights arrive/depart from London Heathrow Airport, would the UK Visitor in Transit Visa be enough?
3. Would it be safer to do Paris-London and London-Amsterdam itinerary instead, since there is a British Airways flight which departs from London Gatwick Airport to Schipol Airport?

Comment: While I believe normally you might qualify for a Visa in Transit, you are going to come up against the issue that London is not normally a stopping-off place between Paris and Frankfurt. If it were the US I would absolutely not try it, as the rules state clearly that the primary purpose of your visit has to be transiting. That would be difficult to argue here - but the UK is probably a little less strict.

Comment: Both of those itineraries are rather roundabout.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I'm just planning to use the flight miles I accumulated which explains the rather odd itinerary. I am planning to take Korean Air from Manila to Paris and Singapore Airlines from Frankfurt to New York. The Paris to London and London to Frankfurt legs, I'll take British Airways since it's pretty cheap to travel multicity.

Comment: It would be faster to take a _train_ from Paris to Frankfurt. Or a €60 flight... Either way, what you're really going to need is a Schengen visa.

Comment: I'll be obtaining a Schengen visa as well, of course. I'm just thinking of saving some $$ by getting a visitor in transit visa instead of a general visitor visa since I'll only be in London for less than 48 hours

Comment: @GayotFow this one is a very interesting as well. The requirements for being considered *exempt* from needing a Transit visa include a phrase about embarking on a "reasonable journey", however no such requirements are spelt out for a normal visa application.

I assume that Flint will be rejected as it's an obvious misuse of the transit visa purpose but can't provide any sources.

Comment: here is the relevant official website: https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/overview the key point is *able to show that the only purpose of your visit to the UK is transit*

Comment: strictly speaking you are transiting through the UK, but if they ask you why you chose to book a journey through London, you better have a good reason

Answer (score 5):

They will look and see that you are arriving from Schengen and departing to Schengen.  This will disqualify you as a bona fide transit case and then it becomes a matter of luck: they will either refuse or reject your application.

If they reject your application, they will refund your fee and probably call you with a brief explanation that you do not qualify.  If they refuse, matters will be worse.

Convoluting your itinerary to obtain more frequent flyer miles is a great idea as long as you leave the UK out of the picture.  You can try transiting through, for example, Rabat or Gomel and it might pay off.